# CSS - set font-size with respect to the width of the container and avoid word-break and overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `h1` element that can contain a very short and long word. Moverever, it has a `64px` font-size.

The `h1` element is in in section element which has  `736px` `max-width`.

If the word is very long, it goes over its container and over the `documentElement` on mobile. for example:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
<h1> 
  Transmissionselektronenmikroskop
</h1>

<h1> 
  Mikroskop
</h1>
```

I can use CSS to break it, but the problem is the browser might break it from somewhere that it may not be a good fit.

I can use `<wbr>` element to let the browser break these words from where that I prefer. However, it is cumbersome and I might have many more long words in the future.

I rather prefer to change font-size than breaking it.

#### How to set as much font-size such that h1 does not overflow?

*I want to change the font-size of h1 only if it overflows otherwise.*

Comment: you can use media queries to set font size for 3 screen size, mobile, tablet and default one

Answer (score 1):

If your container is full-width (i.e. spans the full width of the viewport / browser window), you could use the `vw` unit for your font-size setting (1vw = 1% of the viewport width, i.e. a relative setting)

Otherwise you might also want to use fittext, a script that calculates font-size depending on the container width (not only viewport): http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: Thank! No, it is not container is not full-width. Its max-width is 736px.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to break the word and just want to change the font-size I think that js is the only way, something like that:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const wrapperWidth = wrapper.clientWidth;
const allTitles = wrapper.querySelectorAll('h1');


allTitles.forEach(title => {
  if(title.clientWidth > wrapperWidth){
    const titleFontSize = window.getComputedStyle(title, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');

    const newFontSize = parseInt(titleFontSize) / (title.clientWidth / wrapperWidth);
    title.style.fontSize = newFontSize + 'px';
  }
});
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 64px;
  width: fit-content;
}
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1> 
    Transmissionselektronenmikroskop
  </h1>

  <h1> 
    Mikroskop
  </h1>
</div>
```

With this, all the h1 that are bigger than the parent box will be set to a font-size that allows all the text to be shown (this the example on a wrapper that is 400px, but it will work on everything, just remember to apply the "width: fit-content" to the h1)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @media only screen AND (max-width: 700px) {
  h1 {
   font-size: 100%;
  }
 }
```

You can set the max-width yourself, 700 seems fine.